# How can the Na+-dependent Cl/HC03-pump pump several molecules against their gradient?

Tags: biochemistry, membrane-transport

The molecular biology of the cell (6 ed) claims that:

> "Another [antiporter] [...] is a $Na^+$-driven$Cl^--HCO_3$-exchanger
> hat couples an influx of $Na^+$ to an efflux of $Cl^-$ and $H^+$. (so
> that $NaCO_3$ comes in and HCl gets out)"

In the next paragraph, (regarding a transporter with an opposite direction) we can read that:

> "The movement of $HCO_3$ in this case is normally out of the cell,
> down its elecrochemical gradient, which decreases the pH of the
> cytosol".

Meaning that intracellular concentrations of $HCO_3$ typically must be higher thatn extracellular concentrations. In addition, [Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/human-biology/neuron-nervous-system/a/the-membrane-potential) (among other sources) tell us that the extracellular concentration of $Cl^-$ is higher than intracellular concentration.

This means that for the price of one $Na^+$, the pump is moving two molecules ($HCO_3$ and $Cl^-$) against their gradients. How is this possible?

Is the $Na^+$-gradient really so strong that it can power this simultanous unfavourable transport? Or are multiple $Na^+$ ions used? Have I misinperpreted the intracellular/extracellular concentrations of  $Cl^-$ and $HCO_3$?